# VBA assign a range of cells a specific set of values

Tags: vba, excel

At the beginning of my macro I need to have a certain range of cells in column R filled with the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... up to 40. Hence 0 to 40 in increments of 1. This is the simple code I propose to use but what formula after the `=` sign can I use to do this?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 

    .Range("R17:R57") =

End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop, which will increment a variable by 1. For example,

```
For i = 0 To 39
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i+17, 18).Value = i
Next i
```

This will fill R17 through R57 with values 0 through 40.

Comment: Worked well!! Appreciated